# Mongoose push id from products table into users table

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, pug

I currently have a Users model and a Products model.  I am trying to push the id of a specific product into an array called products in the Users schema.

Basically I am trying to do something like this

```
router.post('/setproduct', function(req, res) {
  var product = new models.Product({
    name:           req.body.prodName,
    price:       req.body.price,
    color:          req.body.color
  });
  product.save(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      var error = 'Something bad happened! Please try again.';
      res.render('setproduct.jade', { error: error }, {csrfToken: req.csrfToken() });
    } else {

      /* PUSH PRODUCT.ID TO USER.PRODUCTS ARRAY */

      res.redirect('/dashboard');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator.

```
product.save(function(err, doc) {
  if (err) {
    var error = 'Something bad happened! Please try again.';
    res.render('setproduct.jade', { error: error }, {csrfToken: req.csrfToken() });
  } else {
    var uid = req.user._id;
    Users.update({ _id: uid }, { $push: { products: doc._id } }, function(err) {
      if (err) // Handle error...
      res.redirect('/dashboard');
    });
  }
});
```

I'm only assuming you have access to the users' `_id` in your route with something like `req.user._id`.

A friendly advice is that you skip Mongoose completely and just use the raw [MongoDB Node.js Driver](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native) ([docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/)) as it's much simpler and MongoDB is schema-less so it makes very little sense to enforce a schema on your collections and you will likely get better performance as well. Although that's just personal preference so it's completely up to you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this worked for me...i cannot up vote as I am a noob on here :(